# The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, null-safety

Currently, I am working on updating the codebase for a Flutter project which was developed on previous versions. The error occurred once we updated to the latest version of Dart and Flutter.

The code here is related to when we are returning the list from the `FutureBuilder`.

```
          body: new FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? new ItemList(
                      list: snapshot.data, <--- error in here
                    )
                  : new Center(
                      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
            },
          ),
```

> Flutter Version: 2.2.2
>
> Dart Version: 2.13.3

Please help me to point out which part that I should take care of for this one.
Thank you!

Comment: Did it work with flutter 2.2 before you migrated to dart NNBD?  And don't tell me you mistakenly tried to do both of those at once....

Comment: Yes, it worked before I updated to the NNBD Version. @RandalSchwartz

Comment: And you did the full "verify upgrade versions" and "dart migrate" steps?

Answer (score 9):

Your `snapshot.data` can be null but the `ItemList` class's `list` not accept any `null` value. That’s why you are getting this error.

If you can ensure that, the `snapshot.data` will always be a non null value then you should use `snapshot.data!` to avoid this error. But if there is any chance to be the `snapshot.data` can be null then `snapshot.data!` will give you another exception. In that case you should use

```
ItemList(
           list: snapshot.data??[],
         )
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug arising from the new `null-safety` feature added to Dart.

Depending on how you want to handle `null` values in `ItemList` you should either update your code in `ItemList` to accept `null` (that is define `list` as `List? list`) or update `snapshot.data` to `snapshot.data??` and provide a value for when the `snapshot.data` is `null`.

Additional Reading:

1. You can read more about it [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety)
2. You can also follow a guide on migrating to null-safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: You're welcome, Its only a brief example and a quick answer. Do read up more on null-safety (links in the answer). The code you need to update is more likely `ItemList` and not the `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method**.

> final response = await http.get(url);
> final _data =json.decode(response.body);
> (_data != null) {
> final extractedData = _data as Map<String, dynamic>; }